# How do I Bind both LeftClick and LeftDoubleClick on same control

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to bind LeftClick and LeftDoubleClick to a button.

```
<Button Background="Gray" >
                        <Button.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandOpenSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandExpandItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </Button.InputBindings>
                    <StackPanel  >
                        <Path Width="39" Height="39" Fill="Black" Stretch="Uniform"  Data="F1 M 0,3.05176e-005L 0,29.22L 23.94,29.22L 23.94,7.95331L 16.1561,3.05176e-005L 0,3.05176e-005 Z M 3.30002,3.30005L 14.4,3.30005L 14.4,9.06003L 20.64,9.06003L 20.64,25.92L 3.30002,25.92L 3.30002,3.30005 Z M 5.70001,13.0283L 18.24,13.0283L 18.24,14.4L 5.70001,14.4L 5.70001,13.0283 Z M 5.70001,16.74L 18.24,16.74L 18.24,18.24L 5.70001,18.24L 5.70001,16.74 Z M 5.70001,20.58L 18.24,20.58L 18.24,22.1218L 5.70001,22.1218L 5.70001,20.58 Z "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PartData.Name}" ></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
```

This seems to work sometimes, although it's very sensitive and the LeftClick mouse action captures most of the clicks even though I'm obviously double-clicking. Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused...do you not want your left click to fire when you double click? Because that can't happen. The left click event will fire the instant you left click, even if your next input makes it a double click.

You can manually check for a double click based off of time between inputs, but your left click will be delayed as long as your double click threshold is, so say you allow 200 milliseconds between left clicks to count as a double click, you can't fire your left click event until 201 milliseconds passes.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an older post...

For you mouse bindings, you can use the gesture property of the binding.

```
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandExpandItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandExpandItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
```